# Apply Angular filter with an argument passed by another filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-filters, angular-translate

I need to use the date filter with a format created by another filter. Trying to combine the `date` filter with the `angular-translate` filter.

With a hardcoded format I would have:

```
{{foo | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'}}
```

What I need is to get the date format by another filter.

Something like this:

`{{foo | date:$filter('translate')('global.dateFormatNoTime')}}`

or eventually this:

`{{foo | date:('yyyy-MM-dd' | dateFormat)}}`

`'yyyy-MM-dd'` being default format if the `dateFormat` filter not returning anything.

Right now I do this using a scope variable with the second filter applied on it in the controller.

```
{{foo | date:dateFormat}}
```

but wondering if can this be done directly in the view without another scope variable.

Comment: try, `{{foo | date: filter:translate:'global.dateFormatNoTime' }}` using filter arguments.

Comment: @Sravan this not seems to get the argument `'global.dateFormatNoTime'` of the second filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.filter('myCustomerFilter', function ($filter) {
    return function (date) {
        var dateFormat = $filter('translate')('global.dateFormatNoTime');
        return $filter('date')(date, dateFormat);
    }
});
```

And you can use this custom filter in your view.

```
{{foo | myCustomerFilter}}
```

Or if you want to pass the translate parameter into your filter you can define your custom filter like the below,

```
.filter('myCustomerFilter', function ($filter) {
    return function (input, date, translateOption) {
        var dateFormat = $filter('translate')(translateOption);
        return $filter('date')(dateFormat);
    }
});
```

And in your view you can pass the translate parameter into your custom filter.

```
{{foo | myCustomerFilter : 'global.dateFormatNoTime'}}
```

Comment: ok, it works now, but you need to add the date parameter in the second example too.